# How to dynamically change a google maps marker after its added

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Using the google maps API (v3) I can successfully add an array of markers to the map using custom icons.

Each marker represents a destination and I want to change the icon image when the respective destination name is mouse'd over elsewhere on the page.

I can add the event listener to pick up the mouse over, and I know I can use marker.setIcon("imgurl") to change the icon, however what I can't figure out is how to reference the specific marker to be changed?

I've read that I can add an "id" when defining the marker, however I can't figure out how to use this is conjunction with marker.seticon to update that specific marker.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have ID numbers for each destination, keep an array of the markers indexed by your destination.

For example,

```
var myMarkers = []
for(var i = 0; i < destinations.length; i++) {
  myMarkers[destination[i].id] = new google.maps.Marker(markerOpts)
}
```

and in your destination links elsewhere:

```
onclick = function() {
    myMarkers[destinationID].setIcon(otherIcon)
}
```

Comment: WOW, thanks for the quick response. The destinations aren't stored in an array as such but your code was enough for me me to store the handler to reference the change later. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I typically create an array called markersArray. Then I name each marker marker_1, marker_2, etc. using a for loop. After each one is created, I push it to the markersArray. Now you can reference each marker using markersArray[i].